# Which driver ethernet is using?

Tags: kernel, driver, ethernet

I am trying to understanding which driver is used for ethernet (eth1) in my system. From google, I understood that we can check sysfs and got following output.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 May 13 01:36 driver -> ../../../bus/of_platform/drivers/fsl_dpa
```

From output, I'm still not able to figure out which driver ethernet is using. Also, There is no module file inside driver folder which i can check. My kernel is 2.6.34.

Can someone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [ethtool](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ethtool) helps you finding the driver used for that interface as below,

```
Linux:~$ ethtool -i eth0
driver: r8169
version: 2.3LK-NAPI
firmware-version: rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12
bus-info: 0000:0c:00.0
...
```

Comment: ethtool output is fsl_dpa in my case. Any idea where can i find its code?